# Is Batman a scientist?

Tags: dc, batman, science

Batman clearly does a lot of research and development (apparently on his own in many timelines). The [question has been posed before](http://scienceblogs.com/worldsfair/2006/06/batmans_a_scientist_a_legitima.php).

[Is Batman a scientist?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcMEckOyoaM)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, Batman is a scientist.  But not all scientists are Batman.  (Sorry, Homer.)

From [Batman (Bruce Wayne)](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_%28Bruce_Wayne%29) at the [DC Comics Database](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page):

> - **Genius-Level Intellect:** Batman is a brilliant, virtually peerless, detective, strategist, **scientist**, tactician, and commander; he is widely regarded as one of the keenest analytical minds on the planet. Given his lack of superpowers, he often uses cunning and planning to outwit his foes, rather than simply "out-fighting" them. [*emphasis added*]

Comment: +1 for the Homer reference, which was immediately going to be my answer.

Comment: If Batman's peerless, then who reviews his science?!

Comment: Is there any example of Batman following [Scienific Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method)? If not, he's not a scientist no matter what DC artists/writers claim!

Comment: BTW, welcome to SciFi.SE. There are even people here who don't hate Perl, if you drop into chat :)

Comment: @Keen - Bruce Wayne

Answer (score 9):

Taken from [Batman The Complete History: The Life and Times of the Dark Knight](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0811824705)

[image: Comic book page showing a maturing bruce wayne]

The bottom left cell reads:

> As the years pass Bruce Wayne prepares himself for his career. He becomes a master scientist.